# How to implement custom logic using binary tree?

Tags: c#, .net, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to build an app to build a binary tree using 3 methods like: `AddBalancedTypeItem()`, `AddLeftTypeItem()` and `AddRightTypeItem()` using C#.
I need 3 different logic to use while adding an item to the tree: **balanced**, **left** and **right**. I would like to use native framework 4 if it is not takes a lot of time, otherwise third-party code is also acceptable. I need to build binary tree using these 3 methods.

I need an advice how to implement my custom logic and my questions are:

1. Shell I use native framework or third-party libraries ? Which one?
2. How to build binary tree for my app needs?
3. Is there any "ugly"-fast solution ? (I need to use it just for demo)

---

[image: 3 Three types of binary tree]

Answer (score 0):

Building a binary tree is not hard to do, there are loads of examples on the web. A quick search finds these: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/19b1bd/insertion-deletion-in-a-binary-search-tree-using-C-Sharp/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18976/A-simple-Binary-Search-Tree-written-in-C

But I shall answer your questions:

1) I don't see why any third party libraries are needed for such a simple program

2) Search on the web (i.e. the link above)

3) You could copy and paste the above examples for a really quick demo

Comment: Hi, I saw that examples already. Per my question I need to code 3 methods to add data to a node in 3 different way which are presented on image. I need an advice how to write these methods using some of common classes in framework or libraries for binary trees. As you can see image in 1 case I need next item to be balanced, in 2 case i need add item to last right part of tree and in 3 case to the last left part of tree. I need an advice how to achieve this logic.

Comment: If you are going to create logic on a binary tree you first need a model. Do you have a binary tree model?

Comment: I saw some examples already but I do not make choice for model yet, so I post that question. I need an advice which model is suite for my needs according to the methods which I have to write. I have just data and logic I need to implement on it. I have to search in a tree last right element or last left element also I need balanced logic. Which model I have to use?